# How to modify a child page link with php on Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Hi stackoverflow community,

Well the think is that I have my custom menu already set for all the pages (no problem with that) the options are being getting by:

`$links = wp_kses(wp_nav_menu($parameters), $allowed_tags);` (I just allow anchor tags and its attributes)

and then:

```
<nav class="menu-navigation">
 <?php
 echo $links;
 ?>
</nav>
```

Everything cool so far, however some options on the menu are sections of some pages, like:

**Home#contact**

Evidently on other pages like the blog page if a don't have the contact section but I click that option it should redirection the user to **Home#contact** otherwise do not reload the page and just go to the **#contact** section.

So I want to detect with `php`  which options are child and modify its href depending on the current page. I don't know `php` enough though so please any ideas and clear walkthrough to get this done?

Thanks in advance.

*PD: I would like to avoid use JS if it is possible*

---

Update:

Following the approach of several nav menus

This is my current header-nav code: https://gist.github.com/duranmla/e70cc6073dfb2d79e19f and I make the navigations as suggested. Finally here my dashboard https://www.evernote.com/shard/s243/sh/9896863b-c10b-4e32-bad9-5bbc4341cfd9/d373ab95d0c3c3f5d72f455c03dea7d4/deep/0/Fullscreen-8-15-14,-11-35-AM.png

Comment: simmerdesigns, sorry I'm not so good at php yet may seems silly but for some reason I can't make it work, this is my current header-nav code: https://gist.github.com/duranmla/e70cc6073dfb2d79e19f and I make the navigations as you suggest. Could you help me a little more please? and here you can see my dashboard https://www.evernote.com/shard/s243/sh/9896863b-c10b-4e32-bad9-5bbc4341cfd9/d373ab95d0c3c3f5d72f455c03dea7d4/deep/0/Fullscreen-8-15-14,-11-35-AM.png

Comment: What is not working now?

Comment: The anchors that I get are empty my nav doesn't shows anything

Comment: seems like `wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'home_navigation')); ` for some reason (likely some mistake that I'd made) the fuction doesn't work properly

Comment: The problem is that your `register_nav_menus()` isn't being called. Check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus#Register_Menus  - that second example is exactly what you need to do. Also note that this goes in your theme's `functions.php`, not in your header nav template. Once that's wired up correctly, you'll see your additional menus show up at the bottom of the Menu Settings area, like this: http://cl.ly/image/321J252T3k0C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, wrapping `wp_nav_menu()` with `wp_kses()` seems unnecessary.

To answer your question, one easy way without much coding would be to create two Menus - one for display on the pages that have a contact section, one for use everywhere else.

In your theme package, you'll need to be sure there are two menu locations registered.

```
register_nav_menus(
  array(
    'home_navigation' => __('Home Navigation'),
    'primary_navigation' => __('Primary Navigation')
  )
);
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus

Then create your menu items in the WordPress admin, under Appearance > Menus. In the first menu, make your link "`#contact`", and in the second, "`/#contact`".

Then in your theme's header.php template, you'll need to indicate which nav menu to use. Here's what it would look like if your home page is the only page which requires the alternate menu:

```
if(is_front_page()){

  wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'home_navigation'));

} else {

  wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary_navigation'));

}
```

Comment: Hi, @simmerdesigns thanks for your reply, sorry about my delay I'm very hurry about find the solution but I move this task for today since I didn't know how to deal with this. I'm working with your approach lets see... I will keep you posted, thanks again